# Kiwi TCMS XML-RPC not working on Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, kiwi-tcms

I'm running the latest version of Kiwi TCMS (7.0). How do i get the XML-RPC working.

I'm trying to create bulk import feature by uploading csv and using the tcms-api to create the test cases.

Tried the api-scripts repository on https://public.tenant.kiwitcms.org, where the code works and creates the test cases as expected.

But when I try this with the docker container, it fails with following error.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kiwi_tcms.py", line 308, in <module>
    rpc_client = tcms_api.TCMS().exec
  File "/home/USERNAME/venv/kiwi_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tcms_api/__init__.py", line 96, in __init__
    config['tcms']['url']).server
  File "/home/USERNAME/venv/kiwi_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tcms_api/xmlrpc.py", line 111, in __init__
    self.server.Auth.login(username, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1112, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1452, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1154, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1187, in single_request
    dict(resp.getheaders())
xmlrpc.client.ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for kiwi.username.com/xml-rpc/: 302 Found>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to access HTTP and get redirected to HTTPS. Post your tcms.conf for more details.